# Iterating over private data member

Tags: java, oop

I have class Data, that holds different data structures related to common topic.

```
public class Data {
      DataTypeA  structureA;
      DataTypeB  structureB;
      DataTypeC  structureC;
}

public class DataTypeA extends ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> {
}
```

I want to write code that iterates over structureA and performs some operations based on values in each entry and relevant values taken from structureC.

I have a dillema where it is most correct to put this code, from OO point of view.
The options:

1. In some other class that knows when the scan should be executed and what to do with the data. How can I do it without exposing how structureA is implemented?
2. At Data class. It has access both to structureA and structure C, but I don't want to expose their implementation to Data class either.
3. At DataTypeA class. But then it will have to ask data from another class existing of which it doesn't have to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I think **option 3** is better and you can take required class as method parameter, in this case you can take **structureC** as method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

From OOP point of view, data must not escape objects, so behavior should exist inside each object. Each object should hold all data that it needs. So, if DataTypeA cannot do the job on its own and needs data from a DataTypeC structure, you should combine them in single object which will do the job, for example:

```
public class MyObject {
    private final DataTypeA dataA;
    private final DataTypeC dataC;

    public void doSomething() {
        // use dataA and dataC
    }
}
```